# Record is getting inserted only one time in MongoDB Document

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a employee controller and trying to add records to employee document in MongoDB. But the problem is that record is getting inserted only one time. When i add new record it is not inserting.

Here is my code

```
public class Employee
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View(new Employee());
}
```

controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Employee employee)
{
    var collection = GetEmployeeCollection();

    collection.CreateIndex(new IndexKeysBuilder().Ascending("EmployeeNameUnique"), IndexOptions.SetUnique(true));
    collection.Insert(employee);

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

public MongoCollection<Employee> GetEmployeeCollection()
    {
        var con = new MongoConnectionStringBuilder(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MongoDBConnection"].ConnectionString);
        var server = MongoServer.Create(con);
        var db = server.GetDatabase(con.DatabaseName);

        return db.GetCollection<Employee>("employee");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because of unique name constraint. I dropped the constraints and it is working fine.

```
collection.DropAllIndexes()
```